# Laravel Multiple Optional Parameter Not Working and Two Back Slashes in URL

Tags: laravel, optional-parameters

This is my route:

```
Route::get('/edit_atten/{id}/{date}/{c_in?}/{c_out?}', 'AttendanceController@editAttendance');

http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit_atten/31/2017-03-20//12:25:30

 public function editAttendance($id, $date, $c_in=null, $c_out=null)
{
    $this_user = Attendance::find($id);

    $this_user->check_in = $c_in;
    $this_user->check_out = $c_out;


    $this_user->save();

    echo "Success";

}
```

Here, **c_in** & **c_out** are optional parameters.If I submit only **c_out** then URL shows like this: http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit_atten/31/2017-03-20//12:25:30 it creates routes problems. Because two slashes (//) shows in the URL! Though this (**c_in**) parameter is optional, why showing this?

Any solution for these ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Route::get('/edit_atten', 'AttendanceController@editAttendance');
```

http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit_atten?id=31&date2017-03-20&c_out=12:25:30

```
public function editAttendance(Request $request)
{
  $id = $request->input('id');
  $date = $request->input('date');
  $c_in = $request->input('c_in');
  $c_out = $request->input('c_out');

  $this_user = Attendance::find($id);
  $this_user->check_in = $c_in;
  $this_user->check_out = $c_out;
  $this_user->save();

  echo "Success";
}
```

Comment: But, I am sending this data from Ajax using URL. @suthar

Comment: used get method in ajax